# How to sum the values in a KTable (Kafka)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have two KTables. One holds the quantities of stocks I own, and the other holds the latest prices for those stocks.

E.g.,

```
Quantities
Key    Value
AAPL   50
TSLA   100
```

```
Prices
Key    Value
AAPL   10
TSLA   20
```

When there is an update to *either* table, I want to compute the total value of my portfolio and publish it to another topic. In the example above, the total value would be `50 x $10 + 100 x $20 = $2,500`.

What's the best way to do this? I imagine a sensible first step is to join the tables, and compute the value of each position separately. But I don't know how to sum the values in the resulting `KTable` to get the total value of my portfolio?

Comment: Can you show your KStreams code as a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion would be join, grouping by key, then map the product

Form a stream of

```
AAPL (50, 10)
TSLA (10, 20)
```

Then `mapValues` to get

```
AAPL 500 
TSLA 200
```

Once you have the KTable, you can iterate over the KVStore to sum the total values

Comment: Thanks. How can I iterate over the KVStore periodically? Or, preferably, every time a quantity or price changes?

Comment: You could use a ScheduledExecutor for periodic updates, or you could use a separate producer/consumer pair as a notifcation channel

Comment: Thanks. I'm surprised there's not a simpler way with DSL or processor API. Summing values of a KTable on change doesn't seem like a difficult task..

Comment: The table is meant to be a table , not a single value :) You're more than welcome to make a secondary stream that does a `reduce` over all values, resulting in a sum

Comment: As a last step, you can do a `KTable.groupBy().aggregat()` and map all records to the same key and apply a sum in your `aggregation()` -- note, that this would be a non-parallel operation and would not scale.